# get the data attribute of an element

Tags: jquery

I have this html structure.

```
<div class="has_sub">
    <button class="btn">Select Branch</button>
    <button class="btn">Select Others</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#popup-magnific" data-link="http://www.prototype.laravel.com/dwayne-johnson">Dwayne Johnson</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-link="http://www.prototype.laravel.com/kyrie-irving">Kyrie Irving</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-link="http://www.prototype.laravel.com/allen-iverson">Allen Iverson</a></li>
    </ul>
<button class="gobtn">Go</button>
</div>
```

and then a jquery script

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.has_sub').find('.btn:first-child').text($(this).text()); //line 1
    $(this).closest('.has_sub').find('.btn:first-child').attr('data-link',$(this).attr('data-link')); //line 2
});

$('.gobtn').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.has_sub').find('.btn:first-child').attr('data-link')); //line 3
});
```

As you can see from above, line 1 function is to find the first child button (.btn) within the parent element .has_sub and then change the text of it equal to the current clicked anchor tag element text (.dropdown-menu li a).

The line 2 is to get the attribute "data-link" (example, data-link="http://www.prototype.laravel.com/allen-iverson") from the current clicked link (dropdown-menu li a) and then add its attribute (data-link) to the first child button (.btn:first-child).

The line 3 is to alert (that popup thing) the attribute of the first child button element of its parent (.has_sub) but sadly, it doesnt work (line 3).

It seems the line 2 has failed in adding the attribute because it return undefined.

Any help, suggestions, ideas, clues and recommendation to make this work please?

Comment: Seems to work for me: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m5n3o08d/)

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/em5saz6z/. Have you checked the console for elsewhere in the page?

Comment: use `.data('link');` instead of `attr`

Comment: Yeah, works for me too: http://codepen.io/wallek876/pen/gpYNop

Comment: You can use `.data(link)` instead of `.attr('data-link'));`

Comment: Have you added the jQuery library properly ? `.data()` works as good as `.attr('data-...')`. No need to replace it

Comment: You can use `.data('link')` instead of `.attr('data-link'));`

Comment: yes, im sure I have added the jquery library as every scripts works just fine

Comment: Am I incorrect to say your code works as you would expect it to? Maybe there's something else wrong in your code. This fiddle seems to do what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/e8dhc03c/  (edit: haha there are many people telling the same.. a lot did happen in a few minutes without a refresh on the page)

Comment: Yeah. my head is hurting because your jsfiddle and demos are working while mine is not.

Comment: I have no error and console return nothing and also the alert popup stuff gives "undefine" text.

Comment: What happens if you use your console? (in Firefox or Chrome), see any errors?

Comment: Did you wrap your jQuery in `$(document).ready(){ ...  });` ?

Comment: yes, jquery library and document ready stuff is added perfectly

Comment: no errors in console (chrome) as it shows nothing

Comment: but when i tried the alert thing inside the function when a link is clicked, it works just fine

Comment: solved now, I just had to change the code of the line 3, instead of using the .closest, I changed it to .prev('.has_sub') and now it works just fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

On `line 3`, alert will return undefined for initial start because there is no data attribute attached. It works after you click a link. Check out this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/sh7zosdc/3/)**.

Comment: yeah, assume I have already click the link and hit the go button yet still returns undefine.

Comment: solved now, I just had to change the code of the line 3, instead of using the .closest, I changed it to .prev('.has_sub') and now it works just fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can check my demo and tell me if this what you want ?

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.has_sub').find('.btn:first-child').text($(this).text()); //line 1
    $(this).closest('.has_sub').find('.btn:first-child').data('link',$(this).data('link')); //line 2
});

$('.gobtn').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.has_sub').find('.btn:first-child').data('link')); //line 3
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="has_sub">
    <button class="btn">Select Branch</button>
    <button class="btn">Select Others</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#popup-magnific" data-link="http://www.prototype.laravel.com/dwayne-johnson">Dwayne Johnson</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-link="http://www.prototype.laravel.com/kyrie-irving">Kyrie Irving</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-link="http://www.prototype.laravel.com/allen-iverson">Allen Iverson</a></li>
    </ul>
<button class="gobtn">Go</button>
</div>
```

if this what you want your problem is selection of the data attribut you can know more about it here 
https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: still returns undefined

Comment: did you have click on one of the list then click go ?isn't  that what you want ?  it is working for me

Comment: yes I did make sure that I click the link first before hitting the go button yet sadly it still returns undefined.

Comment: solved now, I just had to change the code of the line 3, instead of using the .closest, I changed it to .prev('.has_sub') and now it works just fine. Thank you for the help.